# How does deleting a question impact the reputation of each user who answered it?

Tags: support

Today [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55097), from Jan 7, 2013 got deleted (by a mod). It appears that:

- The author of the question lost all points earned for the question.
- I lost the points earned for my (recent) answer.

But, this question has another answer, posted on Jan 7, 2013. And it appears that the points earned for that answer are not deducted from that user's balance of points.

So what's the logic to yes/no get your points balance corrected when a question gets deleted? Maybe there is something like "answers older then X days are immune to rep changes in case of deletions"?

PS: feel free to migrate this question to meta.SE, it actually applies to any SE site.

Comment: Generic SE questions are fine on child sites. We are not reallly supposed to migrate to MSE for little things. I am almost certain it is already answered there. I'm on mobile, otherwise I would answer this properly. Rep isn't lost when the post hits a certain age.

Comment: It's covered ad nauseum on the main site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work and even has its own blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/. Don't think it needs migrating or even an answer here really

Answer (score 1):

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), which is the canonical reference on how reputation works across the SE network (all SE sites use the same mechanism):

> Deleting and undeleting posts may reverse reputation effects as well,
>   if these posts have votes. Actions previously taken on deleted posts
>   cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), unless the
>   post meets both the following criteria (in which case the reputation
>   effects will be permanent) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)):
>
> - The post had a score of at least +3
> - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days

So, it looks like the posts that results in rep changes did not meet both these criteria, while the one did.

Comment: Aha, there does seem to be "some" rule in place to explain what I've noticed multiple times, merci for the clarification. However, based on the example in my question, it seems "post" is to be translated to "answer". Ie: the user who "posted" the question, did loose the points earned by the question. With all respect, but IMO that doesn't seem consistent to me (the same should apply to the question also). Oh well ...